# Swift/Realm required init() has extra argument in call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I recently took over a larger project that uses realm and I'm running into this issue. The project has multiple targets that share the majority of the code. I need to create a new target, but I'm having a difficult time getting it to compile. I get the error "Extra argument 'schema' in call" and "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" inside all of my realm objects. Here is the code that gives me the error, with the latter two initializers that produce the errors, respectively.

```
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    }
    
    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }
```

Note that this code has no problems working on every other target, just the new one that I am creating. I'm not sure what step I'm missing when creating a new target to allow realm to work. I've tried creating the new target from scratch as well as duplicating another target then editing the changes I need to.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the issue. When creating the new target and adding the files, I didn't realize that the files also had the main project selected in the File Inspector.